# asp.net mvc - how should i make sure my routes are not conflicting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, routes

I am working on a site where people can add their routes to the route collection.
I dont want anyone to write route which can break existing routes.

How can i make sure my routes are not conflicting, and not breaking each other.

Cheers

Parminder

Comment: Any particular reason why you're allowing people to change the route collection? I don't think that was one of the use cases originally intended by the MVC framework.

Comment: I am writing a social networking kind application where third parties can create modules for that. So they can also have their routes which the main application register on start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad routing is gonna break the other routes. This is not something you can leave to the third-parties.

However you can enforce them to define the routing always with a top level fixed route. For example :

```
/ThirdParty1/{controller}/{id}
/ThirPdarty1/{Section}/{controller}/{id}
```

And

```
/ThirdParty2/{controller}/{area}/{id}
```